# Python's sh module - is it at all possible for a script to request input?

Tags: python, sh

Using Python's `sh`, I am running 3rd party shell script that requests my input (not that it matters much, but to be precise, I'm running an Ansible2 playbook with the `--step` option)

As an oversimplification of what is happening, I built a simple bash script that requests an input. I believe that if make this simple example work I can make the original case work too.

So please consider this bash script hello.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Please input your name and press Enter:"
read name
echo "Hello $name"
```

I can run it from python using `sh` module, but it fails to receive my input...

```
import errno
import sh

cmd = sh.Command('./hello.sh')

for line in cmd(_iter=True, _iter_noblock=True):
    if line == errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
        pass
    else:
        print(line)
```

How could I make this work?

Comment: You could use `subprocess`, it's quite simple there.

Comment: In `sh` you can pass command line args, so you can modify your script to take args as well?

Comment: I have updated my question with more details, so to better explain the real problem

Comment: The `_in` method should still work yeah?

Comment: @GaneshK I needed a dynamic and interactive way to type. Please see my answer.

Comment: I see. It's quite nice, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After following [this tutorial](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/tutorials/interacting_with_processes.html?highlight=password), this works for my use case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import errno
import sh
import sys


def sh_interact(char, stdin):
    global aggregated
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    aggregated += char
    if aggregated.endswith(":"):
        val = input()
        stdin.put(val + "\n")


cmd = sh.Command('./hello.sh')
aggregated = ""

cmd(_out=sh_interact, _out_bufsize=0)
```

For example, the output is:

```
$ ./testinput.py
Please input your name and press Enter:arod

Hello arod
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this:

1. Using _in:

using _in, we can pass a list which can be taken as input in the python script

```
cmd = sh.Command('./read.sh')
stdin = ['hello']
for line in cmd(_iter=True, _iter_noblock=True, _in=stdin):
    if line == errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
        pass
    else:
        print(line)
```

2. Using command line args if you are willing to modify the script.